# Angular6 NgModel input bind to async data not work

Tags: angular

Now I am develop an Apollo-GraphQL-Angular demo and get some trouble.

user-detail.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="user">

  <h2>{{user.username | uppercase}} Details</h2>
  <div><span>id: </span>{{user.id}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>username:
      <input [(ngModel)]="user.username" placeholder="username" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <button (click)="save()">save</button>

</div>
```

user-detail.component.ts

```
export class UserDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() user: User;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUser();
  }

  getUser(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.userService.getUser(id)
      .subscribe(user => this.user = user);
  }
}
```

user.service.ts

```
getUser(id: string): Observable<User> {
    // TODO: send the message _after_ fetching the hero
    this.messageService.add(`UserService: fetched user id=${id}`);
    return this.apollo
      .watchQuery({
        query: userQuery,
        variables: {
          userID: id
        }
      })
      .valueChanges.pipe<User>(
        map(({data}: {data: {user: object}}) => data.user)
      );
  }
```

Now on the web page it can display the id and username of current user. However, when I typing a new username in the input element, the current user object does not update.

If I change the code like this, it works well.

```
getUser(): void {
  this.user = {
    id: '1',
    username: 'test'
  }
}
```

So that I think there are some problems about the AsyncPipe data. Is there anyone can help me solve it?

And I have imported `FormsModule` and define `User`

```
export class User {
  id: string;
  username: string;
}
```

Comment: Unless this is missing some code, you're not actually using the async pipe. How are you checking to see if the user object has updated?

Comment: @user184994 1. In `user-detail.component.html`, `<h2>{{user.username | uppercase}} Details</h2>` the text of `user.username` doest not change. 2. there is `save()` to update username, and the log of mongodb tells that

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the browser?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem and fix, give it a look: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q4c4sh

Comment: @user184994 No, it is really strange

Comment: @CharlesAssuncao I reviewed your code and found that you return a constant object in `getUser`, if I replace the data from database it cannot work.

Comment: @Xile It wasn't a const, anyway, look the changes I did there. I'm actually taking the data from the server in that case and achieving what you want